# Problemas con encriptacion

Tags: php, funciones, encriptación, hash

Miren tengo dos proyectos, uno al lado del otro y en uno corre a la perfección y en otro no. miren los códigos:

```
<?php 
    $opciones = [
    'cost' => 11,
    'salt' => "ÑsodEFHbzvuQlIwtvHgVsCsFbaUdjpwsHxwvHBcppgyveqUksQb37695202931484987193162641539158212389566725204804!!·$%&/()=?¿^*Ç¨_:;>|@#¢∞¬÷“”≠´‚[]{}–…„≤<ñ",
];
echo password_hash("ADMIN", PASSWORD_BCRYPT, $opciones)."\n";
?>
```

en este funciona perfectamente y el resultado es: 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

pero si lo hago en mi proyecto completo de la siguiente manera:

```
<?php

function claveEncrypt($clave)
{
    $opciones = [
    'cost' => 11,
    'salt' => "ÑsodEFHbzvuQlIwtvHgVsCsFbaUdjpwsHxwvHBcppgyveqUksQb37695202931484987193162641539158212389566725204804!!·$%&/()=?¿^*Ç¨_:;>|@#¢∞¬÷“”≠´‚[]{}–…„≤<ñ"
];
echo password_hash($clave, PASSWORD_BCRYPT, $opciones)."\n";
}
```

y la llamo de la siguiente manera:

```
<?php
    include "../../utilities/functions.php";
    $link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "user", "clave");
    mysqli_select_db($link, "bd");
    $tildes = $link->query("SET NAMES 'utf8'"); //Para que se muestren las tildes correctamente
    $username=$_POST['username'];
    $clave = claveEncrypt($_POST['password']);
    echo $clave;
    die;
    $result = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$username' AND password='$password'");
    if ($fila = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
        session_start();
        if(isset($_POST['remember'])){
            //setcookie ("nickname",$use, time()+60);
            ini_set('session.cookie_lifetime', 60 * 60 * 24 * 30);
            session_regenerate_id(TRUE);
        }
        $_SESSION['nickname']= $username;
        header('Location: ../../views/administrator/home.iq');
    }else {
        header('Location: ../../views/administrator/admin.html');
    }
?>
```

y el resultado es: [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Alguno sabe que estoy haciendo mal?

Comment: haz un `phpinfo()` sobre tu proyecto en el que no funciona y ve en que versión de php lo estás corriendo

Comment: y si en vez de:

echo password_hash($clave, PASSWORD_BCRYPT, $opciones)."\n";
pusieras:

return password_hash($clave, PASSWORD_BCRYPT, $opciones); en el segundo código?

Comment: `password_hash()` esta disponible a partir de la versión  PHP 5.5 y a partir de la 7.0 la opción de salt es obsoleta.

Comment: @Xerif no creo que sea la version ya que ambos proyectos estan en el mismo servidor, una es `http://seadoglabs.com/iq/prueba/`y otro es `http://seadoglabs.com/iq/tv/admin/` => admin@admin.com : ADMIN

Comment: @PAGANA sigue igual : `Fatal error: Call to undefined function password_hash() in /home4/colitalia/public_html/www.seadoglabs.com/iq/tv/utilities/functions.php on line 9`

Comment: El hecho que este en el mismo servidor es irrelevante, en un mismo servidor puede concurrir múltiples versiones de PHP, aún que sea solo por descartar seria recomendable que lo revises antes que mirar otras cosas.

Comment: @Xerif al parecer si es eso, no tenia ni idea que eso pudiera pasar, pero por que hay unos archivos que corren con la 5.6 y otros con la 5.4? por ejemplo dentro de administrador actualice el administrador con esa funcion, pero a la hora de consultar si la clave en correcta con esa misma funcion no me da, y ambos son el mismo proyecto, el login esta en `/administrator/admin.php` y va a `Controllers/administrator/admin.php` y el de actualizar la clave(el qiue si funciona) esta en `/administrator/home.php` y va a `Controllersadministrator/changePassword.php`